# Accessing Linux kernel structure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-kernel-headers

I'm trying to copy_to_user kernel structure dm_dirty_log in custom syscall(educational task).

I learned some Linux kernel code and found the header where it declared, but I can't understand if it exists only in the stack or this structure is allocated somewhere in kernel space and I can access it from my syscall.

If somebody has any ideas about my problem? How should I do it?

Comment: It seems to be created by `dm_dirty_log_create()` which is called by the code in "drivers/dm/dm-raid1.c" (part of the code for the  `CONFIG_DM_MIRROR` configuration option). [elixir.bootlin.com](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) is a handy site for cross referencing Linux kernel code.